# Use Google Sheets QUERY or array to sum where date=date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I have a spreadsheet with a couple of sheets in it, I want to summarize sales by date.
I'm trying to use the query sum function to summarize everything since I wasn't able to do it with array-formula.

but I'm not able to do it with a query as well. I don't want to just copy-paste the sum function from each row to the next I want to just type the date I need in column A and get all the results in the different column.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Pjdy3Ywa556aZS3k8euJYyd9d-IR7qVsBKFu7luEQwA/edit?usp=sharing

I want the connection between 2 sheets, meetings, and Circulation.
now I need it to summarize the results in meetings!j, where meetings!i = Circulation!A.
then multiply by Circulation!i where Circulation!A =< Circulation!H

I tried everything spent hours on this search and everything and wasn't able to accomplish anything.
would really appreciate some help!

Comment: What is the formula that you tried?

Answer (score 0):

> I want the connection between 2 sheets, meetings, and Circulation. now I need it to summarize the results in meetings!j, where meetings!i = Circulation!A

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TO_TEXT(A2:A), TO_TEXT(QUERY(Meetings!I:J, 
 "select I,sum(J) where I is not null group by I label sum(J)''", 0)), 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

---

> then multiply by Circulation!i where Circulation!A =< Circulation!H

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>"", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TO_TEXT(A2:A), TO_TEXT(QUERY(Meetings!I:J, 
 "select I,sum(J) where I is not null group by I label sum(J)''", 0)), 2, 0))*
 SUM(FILTER(I2:I, A2:A<=H2:H)), ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: thank you it works but not perfectly, it only returns the first value it encounters it dosent keep searching for more values..
meaning, if i add in Meetings!J another value it dosent summarize it..

Comment: if you add value in `meetings!j` you also need to add value in `meetings!i` and such value in `meetings!i` needs to be present in `circulation!A`. if you just need sum table then use `=QUERY(Meetings!I:J, 
 "select I,sum(J) where I is not null group by I label sum(J)''", 0)`

Comment: when i add value in meetings!j i allso add in meeting!i, and the value is present in circulation!A.
Meetings!i and circulation!A both represent month and year. (aug 2019, sep 2019...)

Comment: but it dosent sum it, for example, i added another row in meetings where I(aug 2019) is the same I(aug 2019) and the J value in the row is 2, it didnt update in B column in circulation

Comment: I see. try like this: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TEXT(A2:A, "yyyy mmmm"), 
 QUERY({TEXT(Meetings!I:I, "yyyy mmmm"), Meetings!J:J}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''", 0), 2, 0)))`